# Application Deployment with Powershell

Tags: deployment, powershell

I've developed a Powershell script to deploy updates to a suite of applications; including SQL Server database updates.

Next I need a way to execute these scripts on 100+ servers; without manually connecting to each server.  "Powershell v2 with remoting" is not an option as it is still in CTP.

Powershell v1 with WinRM looks the most promising, but I can't get feedback from my scripts.  The scripts execute, but I need to know about exceptions.  The scripts create a log file, is there a way to send the contents of the log file back to the "client" (the local computer making the remote calls)?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is No. Long version is, possible but will involve lots of hacks. I developed very similar deployment script/system using PowerShell 2 last year. The remoting feature is the primary reason we put up with the CTP status. PowerShell 1 with WinRM is flaky at best and as you said, no real feedback apart from ok or failed.

Alternative that I considered included using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which is very much non-standard and may be blocked by firewall. The other approach involves using system management tools such as MS's System Center, but that's just a big hammer for a tiny nail. So you have to pick your poison...

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on this: The easiest way to capture powershell output is to use the start-transcript cmdlet to pipe console output to a file. We have a small snippet at the start of all our script that sends a log file with the console output from each script to a central file share, and names the log file with script name and date executed so that we'll have an idea of what happened. Its not too hard to pipe all those log files into a database for further processing either. Probably won't seolve all your problems, but would definitely help on the "getting data back" part.

best regards, 
Trond